# HISTTIMEFORMAT syntax

Tags: bash, command-history

There are many `bash` guides that include adding lines such as `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%d/%m/%y %T '` or `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "` to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

There's always a space before the final quote. E.g. it's never `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%d/%m/%y %T'`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the trailing space is not included in HISTTIMEFORMAT, then you won't have a space between the timestamp and the command. Here are some examples:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T: "
```

This results in:

```
33916  2014-12-18 11:03:08: echo foo
```

Without the space:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T:"
33916  2014-12-18 11:04:11:echo foo
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think that, since I had expected there to be a space between each timestamp and command automatically.

Comment: Quote from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-history): "No intervening blank is printed between the formatted time stamp and the history line."